# How to wrtie the for loop out put to a csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, csv

I have a `function` that returns a `list` ..

```
def give_list(number, type, index): 
        list_ = []
        do something 
    return list_
```

The output of this function is in the following format;

```
['Training/1.png', 3450, 3865, 1517, 1789, 'GOOD']
```

Now I use a for loop to get more list like above and write into a `.csv` file..

```
for key, value in dic_.items():
    list_ = give_list(key, "CC", 2)
    df = pd.DataFrame(list_)
    df.to_csv('/path/to/write/testFile.csv', sep=',')
```

For example my loop generate the following output;

```
['Training/1.png', 1255, 4556, 1455, 1789, 'GOOD']
['Training/2.png', 4555, 2899, 6989, 1586, 'BAD']
['Training/3.png', 4744, 2478, 9862, 1755, 'BAD']
['Training/4.png', 3450, 6989, 2455, 3866, 'GOOD']
```

My `df.to_csv('/path/to/write/testFile.csv', sep=',')` inside the for loop does not help me to write the output in the `.csv` file. How can I do this? 
I need to see the output like this in the `.csv` file;

```
'Training/1.png', 1255, 4556, 1455, 1789, 'GOOD'
'Training/2.png', 4555, 2899, 6989, 1586, 'BAD'
'Training/3.png', 4744, 2478, 9862, 1755, 'BAD'
'Training/4.png', 3450, 6989, 2455, 3866, 'GOOD'
```

Comment: Why don't you just do `pd.DataFrame(dict_).to_csv('/path/to/file/)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
import csv 
payload = [give_list(key, "CC", 2) for key in dic_] # create list of lists(rows) payload
with open('/path/to/write/testFile.csv', "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(payload)
```